# Add feature to countvectorizer from different column with FeatureUnion

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, feature-extraction

I currently am trying to add an additional feature to a countvectorizer matrix which is created with scikit-learn.

The workflow is the following:
I've got a dataframe which includes a column with text and one that contains an additional feature.

I first split my data into training and test data dataframes.
Then I apply the countvectorizer on the text column of my training data.
Then I fit a RandomForest classifier with the countvectorizer matrix as input.

What I now am trying to archieve is that I want to run the RandomForest classifier with the matrix and the additional feature which is in an other column of my dataframe.

How would I do this best? I already read about scikit feature-union but could not get this working with a different column in my dataframe.

Here an code example:

```
# Split the data
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.drop(['gender'], axis=1), df['gender'], test_size=0.2)
df_x_train = pandas.DataFrame(x_train)
df_x_test = pandas.DataFrame(x_test)
df_y_train = pandas.DataFrame(y_train)
df_y_test  = pandas.DataFrame(y_test)

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X__train = vectorizer.fit_transform(df_x_train['text']).toarray()
X__test = vectorizer.transform(df_x_test['text']).toarray()

# Now here I would like to add df['feature_new'] to my X_train and X_test

model = RandomForest()
model.fit(X_train, df_y_train['gender'])
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `ColumnTransformer`, not `FeatureUnion`.  The latter applies multiple transformers to every column, whereas the former lets you apply transformers to specific columns.

```py
preproc = ColumnTransformer(
    [('text_vect', CountVectorizer(), 'text')],
    remainder='passthrough',
)
x_train_preproc = preproc.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test_preproc = preproc.transform(x_test)

model.fit(x_train_preproc, y_train)
```

You could add another transformer for the other column(s) instead of just passing them through with `remainder`.  And I'd consider using a `Pipeline` to add the model into the same object as the preprocessing; it saves you some wrangling the "preprocessed" datasets.  Note that the column specification in `ColumnTransformer` is a little finicky as to dimensionality; text preprocessors generally need one-dimensional input.

The `ColumnTransformer`, at least as I've given it, needs dataframes as inputs (so that `text` refers to the column name).  The output of `train_test_split` will be frames if the inputs were, and sklearn methods will all take frames as input just fine, so just drop the frame-casting and array-casting `.toarray()`.